# Pausing and resuming MQTT Inbound Adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-mqtt

**We have:** a converter that takes the messages from mqtt topics, parses, processes those, and after specific validations sends them to the other messaging system. Should the target system be not reachable, we create a specific event and send this through the injected instance of *org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher*.

**We would like to:** in cases the target messaging system is not availbale, to be able to pause (and then later to resume) the consumption of our inbound MQTT adapters.

We do have a collection of references to those adapters, and would like to write the "Toggler" that implements the *ApplicationListener* and based on event either pauses or resumes the consumption.

As any instance of *MessageProducerSupport* the MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter has the protected *doStart()* and *doStop()* methods. Should one try to use those for pausing/resuming purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MessageProducerSupport` extends an `AbstractEndpoint` which implements a `SmartLifecycle` with public `start()` and `stop()`. You simple can call those to stop polling messages from MQTT and restart whenever you need.

Comment: Thanks Artem, will check it out. Seem to have stopped analyzing too soon.